# How do .gitignore on different levels work?

Tags: git, vim

I have a following line in `~/.gitignore` (rules specific to vim):
`[._]*.s[a-w][a-z]`

And local `.gitignore` of the app.

`git status -u` prints the following:

```
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    .gitignore.swp
```

and I indeed didn't add the `.gitignore.swp` to tracked files cause I don't want to!

If I add that `[._]*.s[a-w][a-z]` line to local (project) folder, then `git status -u` outputs:

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   .gitignore
```

Which is expected (I track my `.gitignore`), but notice that temporary vim file is ignored since `la` still prints it.

Since I work with many projects in collaboration with others, I do not want to drag rules that are specific to my work-flow.

Can I have `.gitignore`s in a single place that would affect all projects **my user** is working on?

Comment: To keep the Vim swap file clutter down consider moving all the swap files to a central location. e.g. `set directory^=~/.local/vim/tmp//`. See `:h 'directory'` for more information.

Comment: I don't believe `~/.gitignore` is ever consulted, unless the project you happen to be working with is your home directory... Or, maybe that's a new feature in recent versions of `git` that I haven't had time to upgrade to yet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have it as `~/.config/git/ignore`